# Django Admin - Make previous inline forms uneditable

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have an inline form in Django Admin. When the user edits the modelform all previously filled inline forms are also listed. I just want to allow users to view previously filled inline forms and make them uneditable. But the user can add another form.

I tried using editable=False but this doesn't allow me to fill new form.

[image]

Comment: Probably not (yet): https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15602

Comment: @user2716201 Any idea on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15602 prevents you from doing what you want.

If you split it into two inline admins, one for listing and one for adding, you can achieve what you want, but I don't like this solution:

```
class CommentListInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    readonly_fields = fields
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


class CommentAddInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    extra = 1
    can_delete = False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CommentListInline, CommentAddInline]
```

Comment: Thanks... that is very close to what I require.